# How can I allow users to login only during working hours?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a code which restricts users from login after work hours:
Users should only login from 8:00 to 4:35 :
Bellow is the code I have tried and I managed to make two conditions work but the third condition does not work : any help will be really appreciated :

```
<?php
    # function to get right time of the targeted city
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
    function time_diff_conv($start, $s)
    {
        $string="";
        $t = array( //suffixes
            'd' => 86400,
            'h' => 3600,
            'm' => 60,
        );
        $s = abs($s - $start);
        foreach($t as $key => &$val) {
            $$key = floor($s/$val);
            $s -= ($$key*$val);
            $string .= ($$key==0) ? '' : $$key . "$key ";
        }
        return $string . $s. 's';
    }
$date = date('h:i');
 echo  $date;
 /*Start time for work*/
 $workStart = strtotime("08:00");//am
  /*Stop time for work*/
 $workStop = strtotime("04:35");//pm
 /*This is the current time*/
 $currentTime = strtotime($date); 
 //$fromSatrtToEnd = $workStart->diff($workStop);
 /*This Condition works*/
 if($currentTime >=$workStart){
 echo "Start Working";
 /*This Condition also  works*/
 } else if($currentTime < $workStart){
 echo "You too early at work";
 }
 /*This Condition does not works*/
 else if($currentTime < $workStop){
 echo "Its after work";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicit the period of your date, the program can't recognize that 08:00 it's an AM date and 04:35 it's a PM date.

just change your variable declaration in

```
 /*Start time for work*/
 $workStart = strtotime("08:00 AM");//am
  /*Stop time for work*/
 $workStop = strtotime("04:35 PM");//pm
```

or convert the second variable to an 24-h format:

$workStop = strtotime("16:35 PM");//pm

This way `$workStart` will be correctly evaluated as a minor value compared to `$workStop`.

Then change your if to correctly match the condition:

```
if($currentTime >=$workStart && $current <= $workstop){
    echo "Start Working";
} else if($currentTime < $workStart){
    echo "You too early at work";
}
else if($currentTime > $workStop){ 
    echo "Its after work";
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you : u did a great job now my code works now the reming this is to integrate with the loin code

Answer (score 1):

```
if($currentTime >=$workStart AND $currentTime <= $workStop){
    echo "Start Working";
    /*This Condition also  works*/
} else if($currentTime < $workStart){
    echo "You too early at work";
}
/*This Condition does not works*/
else if($currentTime < $workStop){
    echo "Its after work";
}
```

Your first condition was always true if the time was after the start time. You need to check if it's within the time range.

Comment: when I put this AND $currentTime <= $workStop the if statement does not display anything and if I remove it yes it does :

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have to manage AM/PM hours, you should convert your hours to 24H-format in every line you use them :

```
$date = date('H:i'); // H rather than h
$workStart = strtotime("08:00");
$workStop = strtotime("16:35");
```

and your conditions aren't right you should have something like :

```
if($currentTime >=$workStart AND $current <= $workstop){ // need to check both
    echo "Start Working";
} else if($currentTime < $workStart){
    echo "You too early at work";
}
else if($currentTime > $workStop){ // > rather than <
    echo "Its after work";
}
```

Comment: Great work thanks a lot I combined Kawashita86 Idea with your code then it worked I really appreciated